# Matlab problem on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: matlab

I have been facing problem in starting up the Matlab. I am getting the following error:
MATLAB crash file:/home/user/matlab_crash_dump.4765-1:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Tue Apr 26 20:24:15 2016
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Current Visual      : 0x20 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding    : UTF-8
  GNU C Library       : 2.23 stable
  Host Name           : chaos
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Root         : /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a
  MATLAB Version      : 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Linux 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : The X.Org Foundation (11803000), display :0

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 00007f36d8a660e8
  RCX = 00007f36f827ec60  RDX = 0000000000000006
  RSP = 00007f3773929e50  RBP = 00007f3773929f70
  RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 00007f36d8a3c8a8

   R8 = 0000000000000030   R9 = 0000000000000004
  R10 = 00007f36d8dbcef0  R11 = 00007f36d8a39000
  R12 = 00007f370c53e810  R13 = 0000006900000006
  R14 = 0000000000000006  R15 = 00007f36d8a3d280

  RIP = 00007f378b88056c  EFL = 0000000000010206

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007f378b88056c                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00050540
[  1] 0x00007f378b889681                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00087681
[  2] 0x00007f378b884394                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00066452
[  3] 0x00007f378b888bd9                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00084953
[  4] 0x00007f3788032f09                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00003849
[  5] 0x00007f378b884394                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00066452
[  6] 0x00007f3788033571                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00005489
[  7] 0x00007f3788032fa1                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00004001 dlopen+00000049
[  8] 0x00007f378b60046a /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libut.so+00308330
[  9] 0x00007f377dc01c25 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00560165
[ 10] 0x00007f377dbf4faa /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00507818 _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn8try_loadEv+00000042
[ 11] 0x00007f377e908de5 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmex.so+00146917 _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn4loadEv+00000037
[ 12] 0x00007f377dbe8685 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00456325 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000053
[ 13] 0x00007f377cfd1fee /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+05378030
[ 14] 0x00007f377cf00a71 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04520561
[ 15] 0x00007f377cf017ee /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04524014
[ 16] 0x00007f377cf0d619 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04572697
[ 17] 0x00007f377cf0d783 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04573059
[ 18] 0x00007f377d044b54 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+05847892
[ 19] 0x00007f377ce6386a /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03876970
[ 20] 0x00007f377ced92ce /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04358862
[ 21] 0x00007f377dc3faea /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00813802 _ZN8Mfh_file16dispatch_fh_implEMS_FviPP11mxArray_tagiS2_EiS2_iS2_+00000762
[ 22] 0x00007f377dc3ffb0 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00815024 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000032
[ 23] 0x00007f377ceafd20 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04189472
[ 24] 0x00007f377ce5f432 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03859506
[ 25] 0x00007f377ce61612 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03868178
[ 26] 0x00007f377ce67597 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03892631
[ 27] 0x00007f377ce62cff /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03874047
[ 28] 0x00007f377ce63934 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03877172
[ 29] 0x00007f377ced92ce /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04358862
[ 30] 0x00007f377dc3faea /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00813802 _ZN8Mfh_file16dispatch_fh_implEMS_FviPP11mxArray_tagiS2_EiS2_iS2_+00000762
[ 31] 0x00007f377dc3ffb0 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00815024 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000032
[ 32] 0x00007f3771492edd /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02473693
[ 33] 0x00007f3771493152 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02474322
[ 34] 0x00007f3771427edb /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02035419
[ 35] 0x00007f377142854e /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02037070
[ 36] 0x00007f3771429ddf /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02043359
[ 37] 0x00007f377142f8e0 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02066656
[ 38] 0x00007f377142ad20 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02047264
[ 39] 0x00007f377142ae39 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02047545
[ 40] 0x00007f377142b43c /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02049084
[ 41] 0x00007f377142b608 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02049544
[ 42] 0x00007f377149ce27 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02514471
[ 43] 0x00007f377151eccb /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+03046603
[ 44] 0x00007f377dbe8744 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00456516 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000244
[ 45] 0x00007f377151c451 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+03036241
[ 46] 0x00007f377ceafd20 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04189472
[ 47] 0x00007f377ce5f432 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03859506
[ 48] 0x00007f377ce61612 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03868178
[ 49] 0x00007f377ce67597 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03892631
[ 50] 0x00007f377ce62cff /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03874047
[ 51] 0x00007f377ce63934 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03877172
[ 52] 0x00007f377ced92ce /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04358862
[ 53] 0x00007f377dc3faea /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00813802 _ZN8Mfh_file16dispatch_fh_implEMS_FviPP11mxArray_tagiS2_EiS2_iS2_+00000762
[ 54] 0x00007f377dc3ffb0 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00815024 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000032
[ 55] 0x00007f3771492edd /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02473693
[ 56] 0x00007f37714285c2 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02037186
[ 57] 0x00007f3771429ddf /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02043359
[ 58] 0x00007f377142f8e0 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02066656
[ 59] 0x00007f377142b053 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02048083
[ 60] 0x00007f3771499bb6 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02501558
[ 61] 0x00007f377ce8d6cb /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04048587
[ 62] 0x00007f377dc01305 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00557829
[ 63] 0x00007f377dbe8744 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00456516 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000244
[ 64] 0x00007f377ceafd20 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04189472
[ 65] 0x00007f377ce5f432 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03859506
[ 66] 0x00007f377ce61612 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03868178
[ 67] 0x00007f377ce67597 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03892631
[ 68] 0x00007f377ce62cff /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03874047
[ 69] 0x00007f377ce63934 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03877172
[ 70] 0x00007f377ced92ce /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04358862
[ 71] 0x00007f377dc3faea /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00813802 _ZN8Mfh_file16dispatch_fh_implEMS_FviPP11mxArray_tagiS2_EiS2_iS2_+00000762
[ 72] 0x00007f377dc3ffb0 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00815024 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000032
[ 73] 0x00007f3771492edd /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02473693
[ 74] 0x00007f37714285c2 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02037186
[ 75] 0x00007f3771429ddf /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02043359
[ 76] 0x00007f377142f8e0 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02066656
[ 77] 0x00007f377142b053 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02048083
[ 78] 0x00007f377151eef0 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+03047152
[ 79] 0x00007f377dbe8744 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00456516 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000244
[ 80] 0x00007f377151c451 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+03036241
[ 81] 0x00007f377ceaf98f /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04188559
[ 82] 0x00007f377cec4ca4 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04275364
[ 83] 0x00007f377cec5b0f /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04279055
[ 84] 0x00007f377cec6df0 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04283888
[ 85] 0x00007f377ce41e06 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03739142
[ 86] 0x00007f377ce32005 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03674117
[ 87] 0x00007f377ce606c2 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03864258
[ 88] 0x00007f377ce67597 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03892631
[ 89] 0x00007f377ce62cff /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03874047
[ 90] 0x00007f377ce63934 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03877172
[ 91] 0x00007f377ced92ce /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04358862
[ 92] 0x00007f377dc3faea /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00813802 _ZN8Mfh_file16dispatch_fh_implEMS_FviPP11mxArray_tagiS2_EiS2_iS2_+00000762
[ 93] 0x00007f377dc3ffb0 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00815024 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000032
[ 94] 0x00007f3771492edd /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02473693
[ 95] 0x00007f37714285c2 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02037186
[ 96] 0x00007f3771429ddf /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02043359
[ 97] 0x00007f377142f8e0 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02066656
[ 98] 0x00007f377142b053 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02048083
[ 99] 0x00007f3771499bb6 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02501558
[100] 0x00007f377151e71b /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+03045147
[101] 0x00007f377dbe8744 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00456516 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000244
[102] 0x00007f377151c451 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+03036241
[103] 0x00007f377ce8ce60 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04046432
[104] 0x00007f377ce8c729 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04044585
[105] 0x00007f377cdce986 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03266950 inCallFcnWithTrap+00000086
[106] 0x00007f377ce5350b /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03810571
[107] 0x00007f377cdcff70 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03272560 _Z44inCallFcnWithTrapInDesiredWSAndPublishEventsiPP11mxArray_tagiS1_PKcbP15inWorkSpace_tag+00000096
[108] 0x00007f377ee4ab44 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00908100 _ZN3iqm15BaseFEvalPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000356
[109] 0x00007f3757d9f763 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+00870243 _ZN9nativejmi14JmiFEvalPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000307
[110] 0x00007f3757dc5e15 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+01027605 _ZN3mcr3mvm27McrSwappingIqmPluginAdapterIN9nativejmi14JmiFEvalPluginEE7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000437
[111] 0x00007f377ee45e16 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00888342
[112] 0x00007f377ee2c484 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00783492
[113] 0x00007f377ee2fa20 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00797216 _ZN3iqm3Iqm7deliverERKN10foundation7msg_svc8exchange7RoutingEN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor3IIPEEERKN6mlutil10contextmgr5McrIDERKNS7_8optionalINSD_5MvmIDEEENS8_INS2_8eventmgr8EventMgrEEENSC_14cmddistributor13WhenToDequeue13WhenToDequeueEb+00000144
[114] 0x00007f378320af4b /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmlutil.so+03600203 _ZNK14cmddistributor17IIPEnqueueMessage7deliverERKN10foundation7msg_svc8exchange7RoutingE+00000171
[115] 0x00007f378272902c /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwms.so+02924588 _ZN10foundation7msg_svc8exchange12MessageQueue7deliverERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS1_8EnvelopeEEE+00000172
[116] 0x00007f3782729ee6 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwms.so+02928358
[117] 0x00007f378270c129 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwms.so+02806057
[118] 0x00007f378270efb9 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwms.so+02817977
[119] 0x00007f378270baad /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwms.so+02804397
[120] 0x00007f3783190ee0 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmlutil.so+03100384
[121] 0x00007f3783191804 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmlutil.so+03102724
[122] 0x00007f3757dba456 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+00980054 _ZN14cmddistributor14CmdDistributor21enqueueWithFutureImplIN9nativejmi15FEvalCmdRequestEEEN5boost13unique_futureINS_16CmdRequestTraitsIT_E10ResultTypeEEERKNS4_10shared_ptrIS7_EENS0_14IqmEnqueueTypeEN6mlutil14cmddistributor13WhenToDequeue13WhenToDequeueE+00000262
[123] 0x00007f3757dba682 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+00980610 _ZN14cmddistributor14CmdDistributor10executeNowIN9nativejmi15FEvalCmdRequestEEEN5boost10disable_ifINS4_7is_sameIvNS_16CmdRequestTraitsIT_E10ResultTypeEEESA_E4typeERKNS4_10shared_ptrIS8_EE+00000034
[124] 0x00007f3757da6e06 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+00900614 _Z17mtMessageDispatchP7JNIEnv_P8_jobject+00000310
[125] 0x00007f3757da7145 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+00901445 _Z17SendMatlabMessageP7JNIEnv_P8_jobjectS2_+00000085
[126] 0x00007f37681bdd98                                   <unknown-module>+00000000
[127] 0x00007f37681b1233                                   <unknown-module>+00000000


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

Please help me out. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually a segmentation error is a bug in the program, due to bad memory allocation. Did you try to do what they suggest there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to install matlab-support,but first you'll need to check whether multiverse is already included or not.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If not included yet, then add this line

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main multiverse
```

Update your system and install the package

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install matlab-support
```

Then follow the instruction. It works for me. Source : http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/multiverse/m/matlab-support/install/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and getting matlab-support doesn't helped me instead the following steps solved my problem:-

```
locate libstdc++.so.6
```

and then a long list will open search the matlab option, for me it was :-

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
```

Then change libstdc++.so.6 to libstdc++.so.6.old and libstdc++.so.6.0.17 to libstdc++.so.6.0.17.old by the following commands

```
cd /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/sys/os/glnxa64
```

(or whatever your path is)

```
sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old 
sudo mv libstdc++.so.6.17 libstdc++.so.6.17.old
```

and matlab will work now as explained in Yihui He answer here: [Doesn't Matlab work on ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758892/doesnt-matlab-work-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your answer to explain how renaming components of the GNU Standard C++ Library  will have the affect of stopping matlab from crashing with a Segmentation violation

Comment: I have no idea about that.If you can tell then it will be great help.

Comment: But it solved the problem for me

Comment: Yes, i removed matlab-support and installed it again,but it didn't work.And this problem started for me when i upgraded from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.

Comment: And can you please tell what exactly was causing the segmentation violation problem.

Comment: An attempt to access protected memory generally caused by coding errors.  There are some good examples and explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault It could also be caused by a stuck bit in an area of memory used to store an address pointer - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86/591502

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and adding matlab-support didn't solve it.  However, after installing matlab-support like the posts above suggested, I also changed my video driver after reading GradBK's comment here [Doesn't Matlab work on ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758892/doesnt-matlab-work-on-ubuntu-16-04) and it now works well.

Answer (score 0):

None of the provided answers did it for me, however i got Matlab R2016b to work by disabling gpu rendering to avoid the conflict in the first place.

Simply launch matlab like this:

```
matlab -softwareopengl
```

and you should be fine. I will continue to look for a more satisfying solution though.

Comment: Not sure if this works, but maybe try `LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1 matlab` in the terminal and see if it helps?

Comment: @edwinksl it did for me!

Comment: @flyingsheep Good to know, thanks. I may write a question and answer regarding this.