# Matlab crashes on start "segmentation violation"

Tags: 16.04, matlab

I just installed Matlab on my Ubuntu 16.04. But it crashes immediately with this output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Tue Jul 12 15:33:11 2016
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Current Visual      : 0x21 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding    : UTF-8
  GNU C Library       : 2.23 stable
  Host Name           : saleh-Q1585N
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Root         : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b
  MATLAB Version      : 8.6.0.267246 (R2015b)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Linux 4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : The X.Org Foundation (11803000), display :0

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 00007fd80402e0e8
  RCX = 00007fd82c212c80  RDX = 0000000000000006
  RSP = 00007fd89ee14c80  RBP = 00007fd89ee14da0
  RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 00007fd8040048a8

   R8 = 0000000000000030   R9 = 0000000000000004
  R10 = 00007fd804384ef0  R11 = 00007fd804001000
  R12 = 00007fd8304b1d20  R13 = 0000006900000006
  R14 = 0000000000000006  R15 = 00007fd804005280

  RIP = 00007fd8bb86756c  EFL = 0000000000010206

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007fd8bb86756c                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00050540
[  1] 0x00007fd8bb870681                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00087681
[  2] 0x00007fd8bb86b394                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00066452
[  3] 0x00007fd8bb86fbd9                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00084953
[  4] 0x00007fd8b9c50f09                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00003849
[  5] 0x00007fd8bb86b394                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00066452
[  6] 0x00007fd8b9c51571                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00005489
[  7] 0x00007fd8b9c50fa1                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00004001 dlopen+00000049
[  8] 0x00007fd8b607700a      /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libut.so+00311306
[  9] 0x00007fd8b0d257e5 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00456677
[ 10] 0x00007fd8b0d181af /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00401839 _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn8try_loadEv+00000031
[ 11] 0x00007fd8b0d0fae5 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00367333 _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn4loadEv+00000037
[ 12] 0x00007fd8b0d0cb09 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00355081 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000057
[ 13] 0x00007fd8ab3e28af /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08612015
[ 14] 0x00007fd8ab5067ff /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09807871
[ 15] 0x00007fd8ab4fc47f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09766015
[ 16] 0x00007fd8ab4c9981 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09558401
[ 17] 0x00007fd8ab12bd6c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05766508
[ 18] 0x00007fd8ab1164c1 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05678273
[ 19] 0x00007fd8ab125075 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05738613
[ 20] 0x00007fd8ab2f6033 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+07643187
[ 21] 0x00007fd8ab2bdc40 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+07412800
[ 22] 0x00007fd8ab2c0078 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+07422072
[ 23] 0x00007fd8ab2c0140 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+07422272
[ 24] 0x00007fd8ab3376bc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+07911100
[ 25] 0x00007fd8ab337abc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+07912124
[ 26] 0x00007fd8b0297d0d /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02600205 _Z51inEvalCmdWithLocalReturnInDesiredWSAndPublishEventsRKSbIDsSt11char_traitsIDsESaIDsEEPibbP15inWorkSpace_tag+00000077
[ 27] 0x00007fd8b1e92a12   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00915986 _ZNK3iqm18InternalEvalPlugin24inEvalCmdWithLocalReturnERKSbIDsSt11char_traitsIDsESaIDsEEP15inWorkSpace_tag+00000098
[ 28] 0x00007fd8b1e92bd8   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00916440 _ZN3iqm18InternalEvalPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000120
[ 29] 0x00007fd8729903b2 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+00861106 _ZN9nativejmi21JmiInternalEvalPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000274
[ 30] 0x00007fd8729b5565 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+01013093 _ZN3mcr3mvm27McrSwappingIqmPluginAdapterIN9nativejmi21JmiInternalEvalPluginEE7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000437
[ 31] 0x00007fd8b1e8c1c6   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00889286
[ 32] 0x00007fd8b1e79645   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00812613
[ 33] 0x00007fd8ac9f6bf9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00146425
[ 34] 0x00007fd8ac9f71f4 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00147956
[ 35] 0x00007fd8ac9fc6cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00169677
[ 36] 0x00007fd8ac9fc7bc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00169916
[ 37] 0x00007fd8ac9fcead /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00171693 _Z8mnParserv+00000749
[ 38] 0x00007fd8b104db4f   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00686927 _ZN11mcrInstance30mnParser_on_interpreter_threadEv+00000031
[ 39] 0x00007fd8b103a443   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00607299
[ 40] 0x00007fd8b103aa39   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00608825 _ZN5boost6detail11task_objectIvNS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvRKNS_8functionIFvvEEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIS6_EEEEEEE6do_runEv+00000025
[ 41] 0x00007fd8b103bf47   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00614215 _ZN5boost6detail9task_baseIvE3runEv+00000071
[ 42] 0x00007fd8b103bfa7   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00614311
[ 43] 0x00007fd8b10372fa   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00594682
[ 44] 0x00007fd8a49f66b6   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00313014
[ 45] 0x00007fd8a49dc862   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00206946
[ 46] 0x00007fd8b19cd0df /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+03002591
[ 47] 0x00007fd8b19cd24c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+03002956
[ 48] 0x00007fd8b19ced9f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+03009951
[ 49] 0x00007fd8b19cf84c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+03012684 _Z25svWS_ProcessPendingEventsiib+00000092
[ 50] 0x00007fd8b10379b8   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00596408
[ 51] 0x00007fd8b1037cd4   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00597204
[ 52] 0x00007fd8b1023fed   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00516077
[ 53] 0x00007fd8ba4256fa              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00030458
[ 54] 0x00007fd8ba15bb5d                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+01076061 clone+00000109
[ 55] 0x0000000000000000                                   <unknown-module>+00000000


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just solved the problem by installing `matlab-support`

```
sudo apt-get install matlab-support
```

while installing `matlab-support` choose the user that access to `matlab` and also let `matlab-support` rename GCC libraries for `matlab` when it asked you.

Comment: Something Strange happened, Last day My friend had another error And `matlab-support` again solved the problem!