# How to fix Matlab system error after Mathematica installation?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, ubuntu-gnome, matlab

I installed Mathematica on a system with Matlab already installed.
Matlab started giving a system error as shown in the image. I can not do anything nor even close it. I have to kill it.

[image]

I think it might have to do with the Mathematica installation which asked what to do regarding the `mcc` under `/usr/local/bin`.

I attempted to install Mathematica twice. The second time, I requested that it rename `mcc` to `mcc.old`.
But after I had the Matlab problem I reverted it back and moved the new `mcc` to `mcc.bk` but the problem persists:

Currently this is what I have under `/usr/local/bin`:

```
mcc -> /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/mcc
mcc.bk -> /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.0/Executables/mcc
```

It's also worth mentioning that Mathematica seems to work just fine after this.

User edwinksl indicated in the comments that it is the same as [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/758894/). [This solution worked](https://askubuntu.com/a/758894/110181). So I am marking the question as a duplicate.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: @OwenHines Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Comment: Can you add that to the tags/body?

Comment: Can you please click on that "Details >>" button and include its output in your question?

Comment: Probably the same problem as http://askubuntu.com/questions/758892/doesnt-matlab-work-on-ubuntu-16-04.